# Non-blocking $stdin.gets() in MRuby (not MRI)

Tags: mruby

I am writing an application that requires non-blocking reads of `$stdin`.

Normally (if I were using Ruby rather than mRuby) I would accomplish this via the `Thread` and `Queue` class. Unfortunately, mRuby does not provide these natively and it appears that this [might not be possible](https://github.com/mattn/mruby-thread/issues/9) in the [mruby-thread](https://github.com/mattn/mruby-thread) gem.

**How do I perform a non-blocking read of $stdin.gets() in mRuby, preferably without the use of custom extensions?**

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: @Shimu I did not. I cam close by using the mruby-threads package, but it had issues.